# problem with valueOf(), converting a char to Character in Java

Tags: java, character

I'm trying to convert a char to Character before it gets pushed on a stack but get a "cannot find symbol error", I don't see what the problem might be. This is how I pass the char to the stack:

```
stack.push(valueOf(in));
```

Where 'in' is a char.

Comment: can you post the exact error msg as displayed by the compiler? it tells you where, and often tells you the exact cause. I suspect you just had the wrong scope for one of your variables or methods - is valueOf() statically imported?

Comment: Side note: As of Java 5 (JDK 1.5, whatever) there's autoboxing, so you should be able to pass a `char` as an argument to a method that wants a `Char`. I'm happy to see Java is making these kind of questions less painful these days.

Comment: Aah thanks, that's definitely useful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`valueOf` is a class method of `Character`, among others. You can't just call it without a class to hang it off.

What you're really looking for is

`Character.valueOf(in)` or `new Character(in)`.

Comment: @Carl - Character.valueOf is preferable since it caches and reuses previously created Character instances.

Comment: Yep, I know. Maybe I should take `new` out of my answer. But I really get a kick out of doing `new Boolean(val)`. < ZenMaster > There are as many truths as stars in the heavens! < /ZenMaster >

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for:

```
stack.push(Character.valueOf(in));
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope, `valueOf(char c)` is defined in the same class where you have that call ... ;)